# Text under image using CSS

Tags: html, css

I have an image that looks like this:
[image]

I need to put the text below the image.

Can you tell me where I'm going wrong?

```css
.outer-circle {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #dedede;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.main-div {
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-div">
  <div class="outer-circle">
    <img :src="Commments" style="width: 250px; filter: grayscale(100%); display: block;" />
  </div>
  <br />
  <p style="display: block; text-align: center;">No Comments</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Have a look of [flex-direction](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_flex-direction.asp)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set `flex-direction: column` on `.main-div` (which is set by default to `row`)

Also the `<br>` is not needed

```css
.outer-circle {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #dedede;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.main-div {
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column
}
```

```html
<div class="main-div">
  <div class="outer-circle">
    <img :src="Commments" style="width: 250px; filter: grayscale(100%); display: block;" />
  </div>
 
  <p style="display: block; text-align: center;">No Comments</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to put description to the picture use this:

```
<figure>
 <img :src="Commments" style="width: 250px; filter: grayscale(100%); display: block;">
 <figcaption>no comment</figcaption>
</figure>
```